# Opening Biml Solution Crashes VS2019

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, biml

Yesterday I built a Biml solution in Visual Studio 2019 that worked fine.  Today I opened Visual Studio to the same solution and I get a message box saying "Unable to load one or more breakpoints".  I click 'Ok' and the solution continues to load.  Once all of the SSIS packages finish loading, Visual Studio crashes.  Not sure if I even have a breakpoint in any of the packages, but even if I did, I don't know how to delete it if VS keeps crashing before I can start editing any package.  If I try to open the solution again, I see this warning:

> *A previous session ended unexpectedly.  Disabling this extension BimlExpress 5.0.64108.0 might help.*

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling BimlExpress but that has no effect on the problem.  Any ideas on how to fix this?  So frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with BIML Express 5.0.64108.0 in Visual Studio 2019.  I deleted the ".vs" directory in the solution, which resolved it for me.  Prior to that, I did delete the "bin" and "obj" directories in the project directory, which did not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the Biml files to another solution and the problem seems to have resolved.  Not sure what got corrupted but at least it's working now.